# Can Original Arduino Mega 2560 Work with Google ADK?

Tags: arduino, android

Stupid question fellow Stack users...

Can I use Google's ADK on the original Arduino Mega 2560? From what I can tell, the main difference between the Mega2560 and the Arduino ADK is the addition of the USB host port on the board. I haven't played with ADK yet and cannot seem to find any direct answers via the Tubes.

Your help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need the arduino ADK shield 
http://www.emartee.com/product/42089/Arduino%20ADK%20Shield%20For%20Android 
This works with all kinds of arduinoes :)

Comment: Is this shield required just for programming or to run the developed program later? Reason i ask is that I am wanting to build a project using adk, arduino and ethernet shield to provide web server/android app integration over internet. Guess I am confused as to why the USB host shield is so important.

Comment: You need the USB host shield to be able to connect your arduino to the android device and communicate with it.

Comment: @ThaKidd, you plug your Android device into the USB host port. The host port is not meant to be plugged into a PC. The android device switches to a USB slave device while your accessory hardware becomes a USB host. This is the way they have chosen to do things with Android ADK.